# how to call function from another function in java script

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function which works fine if i call it for jquery event key press or down. but it's not working if i am calling the same function from another function.
like this calling multiply function inside add.

```
 function add(){
    multiply();
    }
```

javascript:

```
     $(function(){

            var input = $('.input'),
        bar = $('.bar'),
        bw = bar.width(),
        percent = bar.find('.percent'),
        ps =  percent.find('span'),
        name = 'rotate';

         input.on('keydown', function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 13){
            var t = $(this), val = t.val();
            if (val >=0 && val <= 100){
                var w = 100-val, pw = (bw*w)/100,
                    pa = {
                        height: w+'%'
                    },
                    cw = (bw-pw)/2,
                    ca = {
                        left: cw
                    }
                ps.animate(pa);
                cs.text(val+'%');
                circle.animate(ca, function(){
                    circle.removeClass(name)
                }).addClass(name);  
            } else {
                alert('range: 0 - 100');
                t.val('');
            }
        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Horizontal bar graph with CSS3 and jQuery</title>
        <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="slider_scripts/cal_impact_on_clinic.js"></script>
        <style>
         #sliderValue140h{ position:absolute;
           margin:0px 0px 0px 330px;
           font-family: Myriad Pro,Normal,strong;
           font-size: 16px;
           border:none;
           background-color:transparent;
           color:#000;
           } 

          #sliderValue150h{ position:absolute;
           margin:0px 0px 0px 330px;
           font-family: Myriad Pro,Normal,strong;
           font-size: 16px;
           border:none;
           background-color:transparent;
           color:#000;
           }    

           #sliderValue160h{ position:absolute;
           margin:0px 0px 0px 330px;
           font-family: Myriad Pro,Normal,strong;
           font-size: 16px;
           border:none;
           background-color:transparent;
           color:#000;
           }                       
         </style>


         <script language="JavaScript" src="slider_scripts/slider.js"></script>
         </head>

         <body>
         <form action="#" method="get" name="demoForm" id="slider"> 

         <div id="sliderimpact2_slide2" ontouchmove="calc(),put_zero();">

         <input name="sliderValue" type="Text" id="sliderValue140h" onChange="A_SLIDERS[5].f_setValue(this.value)" value="5" size="3" readonly>

         <script language="JavaScript">

     var A_TPLh140h = {

    'b_vertical' : false,

    'b_watch': true,

    'n_controlWidth': 356,

    'n_controlHeight': 29,

    'n_sliderWidth': 32,

    'n_sliderHeight': 33,

    'n_pathLeft' : -5,

    'n_pathTop' : -8,

    'n_pathLength' :340,

    's_imgControl': 'images/slide5slider.png',

    's_imgSlider': 'images/Slider Circle 2.png',

    'n_zIndex': 1

         }




        var A_INITh140h = {

    's_form' : 0,

    's_name': 'sliderValue140h',

    'n_minValue' : 0,

    'n_maxValue' : 100,

    'n_value' : 0,

    'n_step' : 5,

       }


      new slider(A_INITh140h, A_TPLh140h);

          </script>

          </div> 
          <br />
           <br />

           <div id="sliderimpact2_slide2" ontouchmove="calc(),put_zero();">

           <input name="sliderValue" type="Text" id="sliderValue150h" onChange="A_SLIDERS[5].f_setValue(this.value)" value="5" size="3" readonly>

           <script language="JavaScript">

         var A_TPLh150h = {

    'b_vertical' : false,

    'b_watch': true,

    'n_controlWidth': 356,

    'n_controlHeight': 29,

    'n_sliderWidth': 32,

    'n_sliderHeight': 33,

    'n_pathLeft' : -5,

    'n_pathTop' : -8,

    'n_pathLength' :340,

    's_imgControl': 'images/slide5slider.png',

    's_imgSlider': 'images/Slider Circle 2.png',

    'n_zIndex': 1

      }



          var A_INITh150h = {

     's_form' : 0,

     's_name': 'sliderValue150h',

     'n_minValue' : 0,

     'n_maxValue' : 100,

     'n_value' : 0,

     'n_step' : 5,

         }

         new slider(A_INITh150h, A_TPLh150h);

            </script>

            </div> 
            <br />
            <br />





    <div id="sliderimpact2_slide2" ontouchmove="calc(),put_zero();">

    <input name="sliderValue" type="Text" id="sliderValue160h" onChange="A_SLIDERS[5].f_setValue(this.value)" value="5" size="3" readonly>

    <script language="JavaScript">

 var A_TPLh160h = {

    'b_vertical' : false,

    'b_watch': true,

    'n_controlWidth': 356,

    'n_controlHeight': 29,

    'n_sliderWidth': 32,

    'n_sliderHeight': 33,

    'n_pathLeft' : -5,

    'n_pathTop' : -8,

    'n_pathLength' :340,

    's_imgControl': 'images/slide5slider.png',

    's_imgSlider': 'images/Slider Circle 2.png',

    'n_zIndex': 1

   }



        var A_INITh160h = {

    's_form' : 0,

    's_name': 'sliderValue160h',

    'n_minValue' : 0,

    'n_maxValue' : 100,

    'n_value' : 0,

    'n_step' : 5,

         }

         new slider(A_INITh160h, A_TPLh160h);

            </script>

            </div> 
            <br />
            <br />
            <br /> 
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

            <img src="images/Show Impact.png" onclick="slidercalsevere();">
            <div class="wrap">
    <div class="bar">
    <div class="percent">
    <span style="width: 100%;"></span>
    </div>
    </div>

            <div class="text">
    <input type="text" class="input"  value="0" id="sliderValue170h"/>
    </div>
    </div>
            </form> 
            </body>
            </html>
```

here is the separate html file only

http://pastebin.com/rsDuEWf3

and here is the script file

http://pastebin.com/Sev6yTnb

Comment: The lack of capitalization and punctuation, combined with blocks of unrelated codes, is making it hard to understand your question. See [ask].

Comment: Would you mind remove unrelated CSS, tags, and truncate your source into a single file before asking the question?

Comment: "It does not work" is *never* an appropriate problem/error description. Please be specific about your problem: What do you expect to happen and what happens? What are the results of your [debugging attempts](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)?

Comment: My is it that hard to get some tidy html with only the needed parts?

Comment: @neuront i have given separate links for the html code and script please check them

Comment: @antony i have given separate links for the html code and script please check them

Comment: @felix kling i have given separate links for the html code and script please check them

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the function on load of the page use ***window.onload = add;***